# How to check if the numbers are in sequence in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to check if the numbers I stored in my LinkedList are in sequence.

Example sets are: 123, 124, 125, 1900, 1901.

If the code encounters the 123, it checks for the next which is 124 until 125 then stops since 1900 is not the next number after 125 when you are naturally counting. So I need to get the indexes of the first(123) and last sequence(125). Then on to the next sequence, 1900 and 1901.

```
    for(int o = 0; o < zeroIndex.size(); o++)
    {
        if(-1 == (zeroIndex.get(o) - zeroIndex.get(o+1)))
        {
            System.out.println(zeroIndex.get(o) + "trailing");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think on how you would do it in your mind, then simply do the same... basically you read a number (x1) and then check the next one (x2), if `x2 - x1 == 1`, this is a sequence, then you check the next one (x3) `x3 - x2 == 1`... and so on. (the condition I show is not necessary the one to use).

Comment: @AxelH I have updated the question, but my problem now is when it reaches to the last index, it returns an out of bounds normally because of the o+1. Is there any other work around you can suggest for this?

Comment: Assuming there are at least two elements in the list `zeroIndex` compare the value of the element at the current and at the previous index. If the difference is exactly `1` it means the numebrs are _trailing_. Store this state in a `boolean` to track how far this state is kept. Every change of this state means a sequence of trailing numbers starts or ends. After the lopp finished and the numbers were still _trailing_ the last sequence would end at the last index of the list `zeroIndex`.

Comment: And I think the word you want to use is "in sequence". `serialized` has a whole different meaning in java.

Comment: And unrelated: dont do this "inverse" notation, where you go `-1 == whatever()`, rather do `whatever() == -1`. That reverse notation only makes sense when you are dealing with references, and want to ensure to not throw up on null pointers.

Comment: The code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because at  `o == 4` `zeroIndex.get(o+1)` is evaluated to `zeroIndex.get(5)`. `5` is out of bounds. So if you're trying to comapre to the next element in the list, ensure you are iterating only to last but one element. You can do this by changing the condition of the `for` loop accordingly.

Comment: If the input list is sorted, binary search can be used. Given example has the elements sorted. Solution can be optimized, using binary search instead of sequential approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String serialIndex = "";
    for(int o = 1; o < zeroIndex.size(); o++)
        {serialIndex += "("+Integer.toString(o-1);
            while(i<zeroIndex.size() && zeroIndex.get(o-1)+1 == zeroIndex.get(o))
            {  i++;
                //System.out.println(zeroIndex.get(o) + "trailing");
            }
         serialIndex = serialIndex+Integer.toString(i-1)+"),";
     }
     System.out.println(serialIndex);
```

We will loop to the linked list and check if the previous is one less than current value.If this condition is true we will increment i else we will break will loop and add that i to ans

**for example**

---

123, 124, 125, 1900, 1901.
we will start from 

124 ----- our **serialIndex** string will be **(0** and 124 is one greater than 123 so we increment i. when we reach 1900 we will break the while loop as 1900 is not 1 greater than 125 and now our serialIndex string will b **(0,2)**.
In the end we will have serialIndex string as **(0,2),(3,4)**

---

I do not have your full code to test so this is best i can do.If you encounter any error please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This works with O(n)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        a.add(124);
        a.add(125);
        a.add(126);
        a.add(1900);
        a.add(1901);

        int index = 0;
        int index1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (i+1 < a.size() && a.get(i) + 1 == a.get(i + 1)) {
                index1 = i + 1;
            } else {
                if (index != index1) {
                    System.out.println(index + " " + index1);
                }
                index = i+1;
                index1 = i+1;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

output

```
0 2
3 4
```

Comment: Be careful. This doesn't work in O(n), but O(n^2) due to small detail. `LinkedList.get(i)` itself has O(n), so using it in a loop results in O(n^2). If you want O(n), either use `ArrayList` or use iterator instead of index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example on how to do it. First, create our list.

```
List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
a.add(124);
a.add(125);
a.add(126);
a.add(1900);
a.add(1901);
```

So, now that we have a list, let start. First, declaring our variables

```
int current; //will hold the current value during the iteration   
int indexStart = 0; //the index of the beginning of the current sequence
int previous = a.get(0); //the previous value

int length = a.size(); //the length (optionnal, but this will be used later)
```

Then, here come the funny par (fully commented)

```
//Iterate from 1 to the end (0 is already in `previous`
for(int i = 1 ; i < length; ++i){
    //get the current value
    current = a.get(i); 

    //if the sequence is broken, print the index and print also the sublist using `List.subList`.
    if(current != previous + 1){ 
        System.out.format("Sequence from %d to %d%n", indexStart, i - 1);
        System.out.println(a.subList(indexStart, i));

        //reset the start of the current sequence
        indexStart = i; 
    }

    //update the previous value with the current for the next iteration.
    previous = current;
}

//Print the last sequence.
System.out.format("Sequence from %d to %d%n", indexStart, length - 1);
System.out.println(a.subList(indexStart, length));
```

This will print :

> Sequence from 0 to 2
>   [124, 125, 126]
>   Sequence from 3 to 4
>   [1900, 1901]

This is quite simple, just iterate the loop and keep the previous and current value to be able check if the sequence is correct or not.

Note that with a `LinkedList`, I would have used an `Iterator` but I need an `int index` so this would have give a longer solution, so to keep this simple, I used `List.get`.